# Why is <a>/href tag not functioning? I have the file on my local machine

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, tags, href

I can't get my head around why when I hover over my logo it isn't linked to the landing page.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="landing.html">
       <img src="img/typeface.png" alt="logo" class="headerlogo">
    </a>
  </header>
 <img src="img/wave.png" alt="wave" draggable="false" class="wave">
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #121420;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

header {
 display: flex;
}

.headerlogo {
 width: 10%;
 height: 55%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 padding-top: 35px;
}

.wave {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

I saw other post stating that the z-index was the problem but I don't have an z-index within my css.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code in a JSfiddle it works just fine (I swapped the image): https://jsfiddle.net/8e0j62zw/

Do you mean like when you click the link it doesn't go anywhere? Just gives you another blank page, or not found error.

If so you might need to check the path on your link to your `landing.html`

It appears to be a relative path which based on the location of your file could be causing it to break. You can read about path linking here: https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: Weird, changing the link to "https :// www. twitter .com" makes no difference I still can't click the logo.

Can't seem to get an image with my cursor in it but when i hover over it it doesn't appear to be clickable and does nothing when i do click.

Comment: Can you make a JS fiddle like I did and paste your code into it? With the logo you're using (you'll have to upload it to imgur or some platform like that) and then I can help you debug it more. Unless I can actually see it and what you're using there isn't much I can do off your description.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the issues the wave image is technically over the top of the entire page although being transparent preventing me from clicking anywhere on the site.

I fixed this problem by applying z-index: -1 to the wave image.